# C++: using-statement of forward-declared class generates error C2371

Tags: c++, typedef, using, forward-declaration

```
//A.h
class A;

//A.cpp
#include A.h
class MyA {};
using A = MyA; // error C2371  'A' : redefinition; different basic types
```

https://ideone.com/Aifxy2

A lot of legacy code uses the class name `A`.

I want new code to use the name `MyA`, without breaking existing code.

However, when I try to do so, I get the error C2371:  'A' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error? Please paste the error into the body of your question.

Comment: @scohe001 It is evident that the name A is redeclared in the same scope.

Comment: @scohe001 error C2371  'A' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Redeclaring the same identifier is not an error. `class A; class A; class A;` is valid.

Comment: Redeclaring an identifier is not an error.  Redefining it is.   Your code is redefining it, not just redeclaring it.   You'll need to modify `A.h` (as used by the "legacy code") and redefine `A` so it refers to your `MyA`.

Comment: @RainingChain Where do you see the same identifier?!!! Your comments do not make a sence.

Comment: @Peter Where am I redefining it? I believe it is only defined once, when I do `using A = MyA;`  When I do `class A;`, I believe I am only declaring it.

Comment: You code states that `A` is the name of a class.  It then states that `A` is a type alias.  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
//A.h
class MyA;
using A = MyA;

//A.cpp
#include A.h
class MyA {};
```